# How to add new line in curl

Tags: bash, curl, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a API request through my telegram bot

`curl -XPOST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chatid&text=*ALERT*\n\n_Hello moderators please upgrade my SQL database for my proper functioning  !\nSet a new DATABASE URL_&parse_mode=markdown'`

But the "\n" doesn't make new lines and the text comes as it is, the markdown is working but the new lines aren't

Comment: You could encode the string with base64

Comment: then after encoding ?

Comment: The api should decode it, so everything is fine

Comment: you mean encoding the text part? but i tried it doesn't decode

Comment: You are using the post-request, so do not put the parameter in the url, see the examples of curl post-requests in https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58 .

Answer (score 2):

ok got it need to use `%0A` instead of `\n`